# Remove JS object reference

Tags: javascript, scope, reference, garbage-collection

Currently I'm solving https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-trigram in JS. When I run the solution against the test case input - it "passes". But when submitting it - it gets `Runtime error`.

The main idea is I have a class (`Trigram`), where using the `input.split(" ").forEach( ... )` (after normalising the input and stuff) I load all the possible trigrams, compare to a candid and if it occurs more times - save to a `var` outside the `forEach`.
In the loop, the objects are initialised within `let` scope (I'm not sure in the terminology).

After googling around, I've found out that the objects are being referenced for ever (despite `let`), so garbage collector does not get rid of them. That is why I get `Runtime error`.

How can I get rid of the unnecessary references?

```
// not the exact code
function processData(input) {
    var candid = new Trigram();

    input.split(" ").forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        let obj = new Trigram(array[index], array[index+1], array[index+2]); // I guess, by using array[n] I'm using some kind of ultimate referencing
        if (magic) {
            candid = obj; // with the test case's input it runs twice
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using `obj` outside the `forEach()`. Using `let` the `obj` variable is in the function scope. Runtime error could be raised for using a `let` variable before of out  of scope.

Comment: I'm using `obj` only inside the anonim function. If some examination is passed I do `candid = obj`. It happens twice with the test case's input.

Comment: "*After googling around, I've found out that the objects are being referenced for ever*" - no, why would they? Maybe link your google results that suggest this.

Comment: There are no direct links. I was reading and testing. And this is what I've found out:
If I use static strings where I init the `Trigram` in the beginning of each loop and not index the array (`let obj = new Trigram("one", "two", "three");`), I don't get a `Runtime error` but `Wrong answer`.